# XLSX from Gmail to Google Sheets: invalid mime type. Content type seems to be application/octet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gmail, xlsx

I'm trying to import an xlsx file from a Gmail Attachment to Google Drive (as Google Sheet) using Google Apps Script. I've tried using the Advanced Drive API in GAS, but doing this results in this error:

> API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Invalid mime type
>   provided

I've figured out that the Gmail attachment is imported to Google Apps Script as application/octet instead of application/vnd.ms-excel, which I think is the problem. However, the attachment is an xlsx file and I don't see why that would be recognised as application/octet.

Keep in mind, I want to convert the XLSX to Google Sheets. Therefore I need the MimeType.
Here's the code:

```
 var mail  = GmailApp.search("XXXXXXX")[0];
  var msg = mail.getMessages()[0]
  var attachment = msg.getAttachments()[0];
  var blob =attachment
  var name = attachment.getName();
  var folderId = 'XXXXXX'; 

  var file = {
    title: 'Converted Spreadsheet',
   parents: [{id: folderId}],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, blob, {convert: true})
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix the error or find another way to convert this XLSX to a sheet?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the mimetype value.

Answer (score 2):

- In your situation, the mimeType of `blob` of the attachment file is `application/octet`.
- `blob` is actually a XLSX file.
- When `blob` of `application/octet` is used with `Drive.Files.insert()`, an error of `Invalid mime type provided` occurs.
- You want to convert the XLSX file of above blob to Google Spreadsheet and create it as a file.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

- When the mimeType of `blob` is `application/octet`,

  - When `Drive.Files.insert({title: 'Converted Spreadsheet', parents: [{id: "root"}], mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, blob, {convert: true})` is run, the error of `Invalid mime type provided` occurs.
  - When `Drive.Files.insert({title: 'Converted Spreadsheet', parents: [{id: "root"}]}, blob, {convert: true})` is run, no error occurs. But the mimeType of created file is `application/octet`. By this, the file cannot be directly opened at Google Drive. In this case, it is required to change the mimeType of created file to XLSX. I think that the reason of this is due to `This field can be left blank, and the mimetype will be determined from the uploaded content's MIME type.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#request-body)

From above situation, in this answer, I would like to propose to set the mimeType of XLSX to `blob` before `Drive.Files.insert` is run.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var blob =attachment
```

#### To:

```
var blob = attachment.setContentType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);  // MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL or MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY
```

or

#### To:

If `blob` has the filename with the extension, you can also use the following script. In this case, the mimeType is automatically given by the extension of the filename.

```
var blob = attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
```

### Note:

- In above modified script, the result is the same with and without `mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS` in `file`.
- In your question, you say `an xlsx file from a Gmail Attachment`. And you say `the Gmail attachment is imported to Google Apps Script as application/octet instead of application/vnd.ms-excel`.

  - If the file is XLSX file, the mimeType is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.
  - If the fie is XLS file, the mimeType is `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

### References:

- [setContentType(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)
- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypefromextension)
- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

These

```
parents: [{id: folderId}],
mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
```

refer to the input file. See [docs here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert). You should skip these.

This snippet worked for me with Google Drive API v2:

```
function abc() {
  var mail = GmailApp.search("SEARCH_TERM")[0];
  var msg = mail.getMessages()[0];
  var blob = msg.getAttachments()[0];
  var file = {
    title: 'Converted Spreadsheet'
  };
  Drive.Files.insert(file, blob, {convert: true});
}
```