# Google Script on Attaching List of excel files from a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I two spreadsheet Main and AddFiles wherein Add file has Two columns Subject and Attachments where under attachments is the list of excel file names with like file1.xlsx and file2.xlsx. Where I uploaded this file in my Google Drive under the Report folder.

I used the code below but always got an error on the last execution. It doesn't recognize the `.getAs(MimeType.xlsx)`

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,1)
data = dataRange.getValues()
var e = data[0][0]
for (var i = 0; i < (e-1); i++) {
draftmail();
}
function draftmail(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1)
var data = dataRange.getValues()
var msg = data[0][0]

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddFiles");

var startRowx = 1
var numRowx = 1
var dataRangeTox = sheet.getRange(startRowx,3,numRowx,1)
var datax = dataRangeTox.getValues()
for (x in datax) {
var rowx = datax[x];
var to = rowx[0];

var Starta = 2 + i
var numRowa = 1
var dataRangeToa = sheet2.getRange(Starta,1,1,1)
var dataa = dataRangeToa.getValues()
for (a in dataa) {
var rowa = dataa[a];
var subject = rowa[0];


var Startb = 2 + i
var numRowb = 1
var dataRangeTob = sheet2.getRange(Startb,2,1,1)
var datab = dataRangeTob.getValues()
for (b in datab) {
var rowb = datab[b];
var datafile = rowb[0];
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(datafile)

var startRowy = 1
var numRowy = 1
var dataRangeToy = sheet.getRange(startRowy,4,numRowy,1)
var datay = dataRangeToy.getValues()
for (y in datay) {
var rowy = datay[y];
var carboncopy = rowy[0];

if (file.hasNext()){ 

GmailApp.createDraft(to,subject,msg,{ cc: carboncopy}, {
 attachments: [file[0].getAs(MimeType.xlsx)],
 })
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Modification points:

Assuming that everything else works properly in your code, you should make the following changes:

- `cc` and `attachments` should be passed as a **single** json object.
- `file[0]` should be `file.next()`.
- `MimeType.xlsx` should be `MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL`.

---

### Solution:

```
GmailApp.createDraft(to,subject,msg,
   { cc: carboncopy,
     attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL)]
})
```

---

### References:

- [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String,Object))
- [Google Apps Script: XLSX from Gmail to Google Sheets: invalid mime type. Content type seems to be application/octet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60693366/google-apps-script-xlsx-from-gmail-to-google-sheets-invalid-mime-type-content)
- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(datafile)
```

it returns a [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) collection, which is not indexed like an array (`file[0]`) but rather requires you to call `file.next()` to get the next file.

In addition, the [MimeType Enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) for an `.xlsx` file is `MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL`.

So change

```
attachments: [file[0].getAs(MimeType.xlsx)]
```

to this instead:

```
attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL)]
```

Comment: I get an Error. Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for GmailApp.createDraft. (line 57, file "draft")